# How to change background image of a body with jquery

Tags: jquery, html, background-image

I am trying to change the background of  a body when a button is clicked 
First i set the background using css like this `body{background-image:url("../images/image.jpg")}` and there is a button with od change and used this jquery code `$("#change").click(function(){$("body").css({"background-image":"url('../images/otherimage.jpg')});` and when i click the button the background just disappears and nothing happens. is there something wrong or another option?

Thanks

Comment: Can you provide more source code? Is `#change` the ID of an element? Did you check your web console for errors?

Comment: No erros on the web console change is the id of the button

Comment: if possible provide with html structure, for better solutions

Answer (score 2):

using:

```
$('elementTag/#Id/.Class').css('background-image', 'url("../images/otherimage.jpg")');
```

Read more at css styling at: http://www.w3schools.com/jquery/jquery_css.asp

With this you can change any css properly dynamically you want :)

Make sure you image is correctly placed in your folder, since the function is detecting on click. Check for image name, its format and formatting.

Answer (score 2):

This might be better without jQuery...

```
document.body.style.backgroundImage = 'url("../images/otherimage.jpg")';
```

Answer (score 1):

Try like the below method

```
$('body').css('background-image', 'url("../images/otherimage.jpg")');
```

Comment: is the otherimage.jpg available in the images directory

Comment: Yes its available

Answer (score 0):

You should check if the image does exist.

Here is an example:

```
<body>
 <button class="btn">Chagne Background</button>
</body>
```

---

```
body{background-image:url("http://farm1.static.flickr.com/159/345009210_1f826cd5a1_m.jpg")}
```

---

```
$('.btn').on('click', function(){
  $('body').css('background-image', 'url(https://www.pickthebrain.com/blog/wp-content/uploads/2015/12/8-things-successful-people-perform-differently-from-others.jpg)')
})
```

http://codepen.io/anon/pen/rrxwQE

Comment: Good suggestion but the image exists i have cross checked it

Comment: OK in this case can you please provide HTML structure?

Answer (score 0):

use body{background:url("../images/image.jpg")}

not body{background-image:url("../images/image.jpg")}